# How can I download Jnlp file embeded in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to download these interactive models.

Please have a look into these files.

http://expeditionworkshed.org/workshed/push-me-pull-me/

I look forward to your prompt reply.

Many Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 0):

### The Solution...

You **can** do it, but it **can** be illegal.

Simply look at the source code of the html page.

Line 103:

```
    <object classid="java:sketch_04.class" 
        type="application/x-java-applet"
        archive="sketch_04.jar,point2line.jar,batikfont.jar,geomerative.jar,controlP5.jar,core.jar"
        width="1200" height="765"
        standby="Loading PushMePullMe software..." 
        style="z-index:2;">
```

So you need to download these files:

```
sketch_04.jar,point2line.jar,batikfont.jar,geomerative.jar,controlP5.jar,core.jar
```

They are all located local, so simply call

```
expeditionworkshed.org/applets/beams/sketch_04/sketch_04.jar
```

and so on.

### But...

be aware that this might not work on your local machine and it might be illegal in right.

I give you this answer only to show how to get Stuff out of the html source code.

Comment: Thank you my friend for your brilliant reply. However, when I downloaded the file, it has not worked.

Comment: I guess it needs local files that you can not download easily.

Comment: Please is there any steps to open jar file in windows 8?

Comment: A jar File is simply opened by "java XX.jar" via console, or, if referenced, by double clicking it.